# Unable to parse JSON reponse in Android

Tags: java, php, android, json

I know this question is very common, but all of the solutions presented doesn't seem to fit my situation. I am trying to retrieve a JSON response from a PHP webservice, but I keep getting this error

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for success
```

Whereas below are my Android codes where I think is relevant to the error

```
        // getting JSON response from PHP web service
JSONObject returnedJSONObj = listsJSONParser.makeHttpRequest(Constant.URL
                + "RetrieveListSVC.php", "GET", params);

Log.d("Returned JSON ", String.valueOf(returnedJSONObj));
success = returnedJSONObj.getInt(Constant.TAG_SUCCESS);

Log.d("JSON Success Value", String.valueOf(success));

if (success == 1){
// do stuff}
```

At the log `Returned JSON` the output I receive in LogCat is

```
D/Returned JSON: {"androidid":"1"}
```

But there is no output for the log `JSON Success Value`. And as shown in the first chunk, there is no value for success. The PHP has been given to me, I didn't code it as I have barely any knowledge in PHP so the service might be the one with the problem. Here is the code that might be relevant

```
<?php
define('IEM_PATH', '../admin/com');
require_once('../admin/includes/config.php');
require_once('../admin/com/lib/IEM.class.php');
require_once ('../admin/com/lib/IEM/DBFACTORY.class.php');
require_once ('../admin/com/lib/IEM/baseAPI.class.php');
require_once ('../admin/com/lib/API/USERS.class.php');
require_once ('../admin/com/lib/IEM/baseRecord.class.php');
require_once ('../admin/com/lib/record/Users.class.php');

    function GetLists($userid = 0, $getUnconfirmedCount = false) {

        $userid = $_REQUEST['userID'];
        if (!$userid) {
        trigger_error('This user object is not loaded with any user.... You will need to supply the userid as a parameter.', E_USER_NOTICE);
            return false;
        }


        if (!$userid) {
            $userid = $this->userid;
        }

        // If user is a "System Admin" or a "List Admin", allow to access all lists
      /*  if ($userid == $this->userid) {
            if ($this->ListAdmin() || $this->listadmintype == 'a') {
                $userid = 0;
            }
        }
      */
        require_once('../admin/functions/api/lists.php');

        $listapi = new Lists_API();
        $returnA =  $listapi->GetListByUserID($userid, $getUnconfirmedCount);
        $returnResult1 = array();
            foreach ($returnA as $key => $value) { 
                //$lists[] = $key;
                $returnResult["contactList"][] = array("listID" => $returnA[$key]['listid'], "name" => $returnA[$key]['name']);
            }
       $returnResult["success"] = 1;
       echo json_encode($returnResult) ;
    }
    //}
    GetLists();
```

The purpose of my question is that I want to know if the problem is with the Java or the PHP codes? Am I dealing with the JSON response correctly or should I do it another way.

Comment: What is `Constant.TAG_SUCCESS` value which you have assigned?

Comment: I think problem with php.

Comment: your returned json doesn't contain any success key then how you gonna have value for that

Comment: @Clairvoyant public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

Comment: run the php script in a browser. do you see any json data displayed on the screen??  -- check/tail the php/apache error log and will show you if the script has errors

Comment: yup there is problem with php side because not closing the tag.You get success but with you get this </br> problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in JSON Response

There is no key "success" in JSON Object.

As I can see, there is only androidid as key in `{"androidid":"1"}` .

Answer (score 0):

Constant.TAG_SUCCESS="androidid";

You are getting **string** not **integer**.
Error is in below statement

```
success = returnedJSONObj.getInt(Constant.TAG_SUCCESS);
```

it should be

```
success = returnedJSONObj.getString(Constant.TAG_SUCCESS);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you have assigned to `Constant.TAG_SUCCESS` is wrong which have mentioned as `success`.

> So change the value of `Constant.TAG_SUCCESS` to 'androidid`or make
>   another variable as`androidID`and assign it a value as`androidid`
>   which will get you the desired output.

and change

```
success = returnedJSONObj.getInt(Constant.TAG_SUCCESS);
```

to

```
success = returnedJSONObj.getString(yourNewVariable); //new variable having value which is your json attribute
```